# Invalid column name C# SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

At first, I got error that USER was incorrect syntax and it should be "[USER]" instead. Now I get that the `ex: {"Invalid column name 'USER'."}`. I don't know what to do, it seems that I either get one error or the other.

```
private void btnEDIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _ID = lblUserID.Text; // THESE ARE TO COLLECT THE INFORMATION FROM THE TEXTBOXES IN WHICH YOU EDIT THE "USERS"
    string _user = tbUser.Text.Trim();
    string _password = tbPassword.Text.Trim().ToLower();
    string _role = tbRole.Text.Trim();

    editDataGrid(_user, _password, _role); // THIS IS FOR UPDATING MY GRID AT THE SAME TIME

    string str = "Update UserValidation SET [USER] = '" + _user + "', PASSWORD = '" + _password + "', ROLE = '" + _role + "' WHERE userID ='" + _ID + "'";
    clsDB.InsUpDel(str); // MY METHOD FOR EXECUTING SQL STATEMENTS
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated - **You code is vulnerable to SQL Injection**. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @GurV . . . Possibly not unrelated.  Passwords are encouraged to have diverse characters in them, such as single quotes or perhaps two hyphens in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the scope of your query. As in, for sure your UserValidation is in the selected database instance you are using on your connection string. Also make sure the that column name is USER and not User or some variation.

Comment: You were right, i feel so stupid now. It's always something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run normal query to be sure all params and columns are correct, then replace param with your field, 3rd are you sure userId is string as you write?

```
UPDATE UserValidation 
SET USER = 'xxxx', PASSWORD = 'xxxx', ROLE = 'xxxx' 
WHERE userID ='xxxx';
```

I recommend to use parameters instead of concatenating together your query ... + 'pram1' + ... + 'paramN'..